# Compile and QPochhammer Function

Tags: special-functions, parallelization, compile

I am running into trouble trying to make a listable function run in parallel. Arguably, the function that I am trying to compile is rather complicated.

Whenever I run the code below

```
f = Compile[{{z, _Complex, 
     1}}, (32 QPochhammer[z[[3]], z[[3]]]^3 QPochhammer[
       E^(I (2 \[Pi] z[[1]] - 2 \[Pi] z[[2]])) z[[3]], 
       z[[3]]] QPochhammer[
       E^(I (-2 \[Pi] z[[1]] + 2 \[Pi] z[[2]])) z[[3]], 
       z[[3]]] QPochhammer[
       E^(I (2 \[Pi] z[[1]] - 2 \[Pi] z[[3]])) z[[3]], 
       z[[3]]] QPochhammer[
       E^(I (2 \[Pi] z[[2]] - 2 \[Pi] z[[3]])) z[[3]], 
       z[[3]]] QPochhammer[
       E^(I (-2 \[Pi] z[[1]] + 2 \[Pi] z[[3]])) z[[3]], 
       z[[3]]] QPochhammer[
       E^(I (-2 \[Pi] z[[2]] + 2 \[Pi] z[[3]])) z[[3]], 
       z[[3]]] QPochhammer[z[[4]]^2, z[[3]]]^3 QPochhammer[
       E^(I (2 \[Pi] z[[1]] - 2 \[Pi] z[[2]])) z[[4]]^2, 
       z[[3]]] QPochhammer[
       E^(I (-2 \[Pi] z[[1]] + 2 \[Pi] z[[2]])) z[[4]]^2, 
       z[[3]]] QPochhammer[
       E^(I (2 \[Pi] z[[1]] - 2 \[Pi] z[[3]])) z[[4]]^2, 
       z[[3]]] QPochhammer[
       E^(I (2 \[Pi] z[[2]] - 2 \[Pi] z[[3]])) z[[4]]^2, 
       z[[3]]] QPochhammer[
       E^(I (-2 \[Pi] z[[1]] + 2 \[Pi] z[[3]])) z[[4]]^2, 
       z[[3]]] QPochhammer[
       E^(I (-2 \[Pi] z[[2]] + 2 \[Pi] z[[3]])) z[[4]]^2, z[[3]]] Sin[
       1/2 (-2 \[Pi] z[[1]] + 2 \[Pi] z[[2]])]^2 Sin[
       1/2 (-2 \[Pi] z[[1]] + 2 \[Pi] z[[3]])]^2 Sin[
       1/2 (-2 \[Pi] z[[2]] + 2 \[Pi] z[[3]])]^2)/(3 QPochhammer[
       z[[4]], z[[3]]]^6 QPochhammer[
       E^(I (2 \[Pi] z[[1]] - 2 \[Pi] z[[2]])) z[[4]], 
       z[[3]]]^2 QPochhammer[
       E^(I (-2 \[Pi] z[[1]] + 2 \[Pi] z[[2]])) z[[4]], 
       z[[3]]]^2 QPochhammer[
       E^(I (2 \[Pi] z[[1]] - 2 \[Pi] z[[3]])) z[[4]], 
       z[[3]]]^2 QPochhammer[
       E^(I (2 \[Pi] z[[2]] - 2 \[Pi] z[[3]])) z[[4]], 
       z[[3]]]^2 QPochhammer[
       E^(I (-2 \[Pi] z[[1]] + 2 \[Pi] z[[3]])) z[[4]], 
       z[[3]]]^2 QPochhammer[
       E^(I (-2 \[Pi] z[[2]] + 2 \[Pi] z[[3]])) z[[4]], z[[3]]]^2), 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True];
dataP = Table[
   1/4 RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}], {i, 1, 100}, {j, 1, 4}];
f@dataP
Clear[f, dataP]
```

I get the following error

```
CompiledFunction::pext: Instruction 3 in <<1>> calls ordinary code that can be evaluated on only one thread at a time.
```

I have no idea why this happens. Note that the first 20 or so lines are just the definition of my function in terms of QPochhamer functions.

Comment: I think it's simply a warning message that the compiled code has to invoke the evaluator and that will not use multithreading. So there will be no speed gain via `Listability` setting.

Comment: Also, special functions like `QPochhammer[]` are generally not compileable.

Comment: To confirm J.M.'s comment, I get only about 30% speedup by compiling this function. Not sure that's worth all the trouble.

Comment: Maybe the OP would benefit from some use of `FunctionCompile`?

Comment: In the end, I found another way to write the function defined above, in terms of an infinite sum (which one can truncate and parallelise easily). @Roman, when you mention you compiled this function, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I meant that I compared the evaluation speed of the uncompiled function with that of the compiled function.